# Sass Module problem with @use and @forward with mixin and Angular 11 CLI

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-cli

I recently updated our design system to use angular 11 and removed node-sass, as the CLI compiler deprecation warning suggested. The app compiles fine.

Next, I was trying to update my scss files to use the newer @use and @forward, but the compiler is not finding a mixin imported that way.

I have built a file tree [as suggested here](https://stefaniefluin.medium.com/the-new-sass-module-system-out-with-import-in-with-use-e1bd8ba032d0)

```
/styles.scss
/utils
   /_index.scss
   /_mixins.scss
/_somefile.scss
```

in styles.scss, the main file defined in angular.json I have

```
@use 'utils' as *;
@use 'somefile';
```

in /utils/_index.scss I have

```
@forward 'mixins';
```

the file _somefile.scss uses a mixin from that file.  When I compile, I get an undefined mixin error.

I realize from posts [such as this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62805050/sass-compile-issue-with-use-and-forward) that it depends on dart-sass, but I thought Angular CLI was using the correct compiler for sass modules. Is this not the case, or is there a config setting I missed?